# How to use as well android's layout to have perfect size on every phone with every screen size

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I'm thinking that google is fall down with layout for these phone. is more difficult understand layout than all the rest.
My problem is to create layout for all the screen.
First i have to set an image for background of activity and then put an imageview in the top with an imagebutton in the top right. I don't know why when i use something like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:weightSum="1">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:src="@drawable/testotrova"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:layout_width="256dip"></ImageView>
    <ImageButton android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.25" android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:src="@drawable/info_mini" android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"></ImageButton>
</LinearLayout>
```

the imageview on emulator is ok but the board of imagebutton is more big than the image itself. i try scaletype but it don't change anything.
When i try this layout on different phone with different screen size, HELL! in a little screen is ok, but in a screen bigger than the first the objects are more little, and posizioned in a bad way :( i've done all for my application but not layout, please help me!

Comment: What exactly do you want, A layout with an imageview on the top center and top right? If you dont want the board of image button, use a simple imageview or button.

Comment: I believe if there were a simple solution to encapsulate all those details from you, the Android guys would certainly do it. There are lots of different Android-powered devices, and if you want to target most of them, you need to put on some work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using a `LinearLayout` and `weight` on every element in the layout!